# Extarcting top ten values from each column and for each year in R programming

Tags: r

I have a three hourly time series from 1998-2018. There are many columns. First column is Time. rest of the each column represent temperature at a specific site. I want to extract top ten values for each year and for each site. I mean from each column I need top ten values for each year. Could any one please help me to solve it in R.

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdyuc.png)

I have shown daily data here.
For each year, now i want to extract first top ten values.  (first ten maximum values) for each station  I have twenty years of data.
so for a given station i will be having 20 *10 =200 values. But i want to do it for all stations. I used dplyr and group_by and top_n option. but there i could do it for only one column. But i need it for every column

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Code and data should not be posted as images since that makes it impossible for us to put them into R to try to solve your problem. Please post them as text output by the `dput` function so we can easily copy and paste it. Since your data is probably too big to show the whole thing, please make a [mcve] of your data that reproduces your issue

Answer (score 1):

The code below uses base R only.
It splits a dataframe `df1` with a column `Time` and 3 columns of numeric values by year and then gets the 10 largest values of each of those dataframes. The number of numeric columns is irrelevant, I have tried to make the code general purpose. The test dataset creation code is at the end.

```
yr <- format(df1[["Time"]], format = "%Y")
res <- lapply(split(df1, yr), function(DF){
  tmp <- sapply(DF[-1], function(x) tail(sort(x), 10))
  y <- format(DF[1, "Time"], format = "%Y")
  data.frame(Year = rep(y, 10), tmp)
})

res[[1]]
#   Year       X1       X2       X3
#1  1998 2.705775 2.783100 2.487363
#2  1998 2.794691 2.864565 2.541577
#3  1998 2.847825 2.897967 2.556129
#4  1998 2.919140 3.027125 2.606993
#5  1998 2.933774 3.052628 2.648899
#6  1998 2.939821 3.088928 2.726570
#7  1998 3.022476 3.103691 2.803609
#8  1998 3.043766 3.244745 2.877455
#9  1998 3.167938 3.408689 3.497455
#10 1998 3.195901 3.499025 3.652625
```

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible

start <- as.POSIXct("1998-01-01 00:00:01")
end <- as.POSIXct("2018-12-31 00:00:01")
d <- seq(start, end, by = "3 hours")
n <- length(d)
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(3*n), nrow = n)
df1 <- data.frame(Time = d)
df1 <- cbind(df1, tmp)
rm(d, tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got top ten values for each year. but would you please tell me,if i want to arrange those top ten values in descending order for each year.

Comment: @P.Yaswanth Use `sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)`.